# How to pipe large amounts of data into C++ binary using lua

Tags: c++, lua

So this is a rather unique request. There is C++ code that I want to execute using Lua. however for my purposes I cannot link the C++ code in the traditional way so I am stuck calling the binary using the `io.popen()` command. I considered using command line args to pass the necessary strings however the size of the strings are very large and will not fit on the command line. This is the current code with a smaller string:

```
local handle = io.popen("./cpp_program [1,2,3,4,5]")
print(handle:read("*a"))
// do something with the standard out
```

How could I pipe a large amount of string data into the C++ binary through standard in?

Comment: Write the c++ data from C++ to a file? And then read that file from lua?

Comment: That is one solution, however i am trying to optimize for speed and I believe that is a very slow approach

Comment: Disclaimer, no experience with this myself (from lua). But you could have a look at pipes and/or shared memory. This seems to be a library that can handle them : https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-luaipc/blob/master/README.md

Comment: `io.popen()` supports reading *or* writing, but not both at once. You could hack something together using `mkfifo` to allow you to communicate with both ends of the subprocess, but you're probably better off following @PKramer's suggestion and using a proper IPC library if you can.